# Using $or (logical query operators) inside $pull (array update operators) does not work in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose to perform the following operation on MongoDB:

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: 'test' },
    {
      '$set': { name: 'test2' },
      '$pull': { some_array: { '$or': [ { name: 2 }, { name: 3 } ] } }
    }, 
    function(err, c) { ... }
)
```

gives the following result seen in mongoose debug logs:

```
Mongoose: examples.findAndModify(
   { name: 'test' }) [] {
       '$pull': { some_array: {} }, '$set': { name: 'test2' } 
   }
   { upsert: false, new: true }
```

some_array: {} - is empty, without $or logical operator. This call causes completely removal of some_array array which is an obvious bug.

Such syntax should be supported, because in mongo shell it does work properly using call:

```
db.examples.findAndModify(
    {query:
       { name: 'test' }, 
     update: 
       {
         '$pull': { some_array: { '$or': [ { name: 2 }, { name: 3 } ] } },
         '$set': { name: 'test2' } 
    }}
)
```

Is it some obvious bug in mongoose driver? If yes, does someone know the corresponding ticket for this issue or it should be reported?

Maybe there is something wrong with mongoose syntax?

Edit:

I've checked also call without $set part:

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: 'test' },
    { '$set': { name: 'test2' }, 
      '$pull': { some_array: { '$or': [ { name: 2, name: 3 } ] } } 
    },
    function(err, c) {...}
);
```

And it also wrongly matches to:

```
Mongoose: examples.findOne({ name: 'test' }) { fields: undefined }
```

Comment: it's odd that the "$or" insite the "$pull" works for you since monngo does not support logical operators on non-top-level expressions in $pull operations. You can see it [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19172)